# "You have backups, right?" Does this sound sardonic / sarcastic?

Tags: meaning-in-context, politeness, sarcasm

Does "You have backups, right?" sound sardonic / sarcastic?

Context: a user finds out that his database is corrupt in a public discussion on a community forum. I suggest that the best approach would be to restore a backup and I also add "You have backups, right?". Right now I'm unsure if this sentence may sound sarcastic or even rude.

I understand that there are much better phrases to confirm if backups exist, but I want to find out if "You have backups, right?" is OK or if its better to avoid this phrase.

Comment: Anything can be sarcastic because sarcasm is a function of speech, not writing. Also, usually, a database would have a single backup, not backups with an s.

Comment: @Lambie - *Au contraire* - you can have nightlies, weeklies, full backups, differential backups, etc.

Comment: @stangdon - if I started work for an outfit that had one backup for its production database, I'd be looking around for a better-organised employer.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey exactly! :)

Comment: @stangdon Of course, backups can be plural. But here, one would say: Don't you have **a backup of your database**? How is that not obvious to you? Your example is a generality, therefore plural but the question is not a generality. Words in exist in context, not in a void.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey All well-organized companies have redundant (backup) systems.

Comment: @stangdon Agreed, not to mention grandfather, father son backups. I used to run 3 sets of 5 tapes (3 weeks - Mon to Fri) so we had 21 backups before we started to reuse them. Oh, and don't keep the tapes in the same room / building as the computers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As phrased it isn't exactly *sarcastic*. How it was spoken would have a bearing on whether it was perceived as sardonic or rude. If you say it with a sneering tone then yes, it's rude.

Sarcasm is usually defined as saying the *opposite of what you mean*, so that doesn't really come across in a question, and adding "*right?*" onto your example makes it a question. A comparable example of sarcasm would be *knowing* the person doesn't have a backup and saying "*don't worry, you can just restore it from your backup*".

If a person were to ask "*you have backups, right?*" while knowing or suspecting that the person did not have any such thing, I'd say there's an argument for describing that as *passive-aggressive* behaviour, which can include using seemingly gentle or innocuous words but with malicious intent. And while enjoying someone's misfortune and losing their digital content may not be deeply malicious, it is certainly not very nice, perhaps best described by the German loanword *schadenfreude*.

If your intention is *not* to sound rude then just keep the question open and ask "*do you have a backup to restore from?*"